# What is the SDL Tridion Reference Implementation version number?

Tags: dxa

I notice the documentation refers to the "first release" of SDL Tridion Reference Implementation and there's a patch that mentions "official version number 1.0.1."

**To be sure, does `1.0.1` refer to the version of the Reference Implementation (not the patch itself)?**

Anyone know if there's a plan on naming conventions for future versions or updates for the Reference Implementation?

Or is the idea that we'll have a version for the latest version of SDL Tridion and related modules? For example, not that the Reference is a module or product, but SiteEdit had version numbers whereas Experience Manager and Translation Manager just seem to ship with the latest version of Tridion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDL Tridion Reference Implementation is not currently "attached" to a given release of Tridion (and hopefully that will remain the case going forward), therefore it does not share version numbers with Tridion.

A similar thing happened with the first release of Device Detection and the Context Engine, which was shipped with version 1.0 (and 1.1), and later was embedded in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 - and lost its version number because it's just "platform".

If things work out as planned, there will be versions of the STRI that have been successfully tested to work with a given version of Tridion, but we do not intend to release STRI as part of the platform - nobody wants to wait 2 years for a new release nowadays, except for some environments where updates every **4 years** seems to be too often :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm still debating if I want to update my environments more or less frequently, but STRI will definitely make this easier.

Comment: And before people start panicking, yes, the Reference Implementation _will_ be supported by SDL. Currently it's not because... well, it's a V1, and we're hoping for the community to help improve and build the _better_ version.